# Query to generate a dataset with 1 row per day

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE T_ACTIVITY_LOG
(
  ACTIVITY_DATE           TIMESTAMP,
  APPLIANCE_ID            NUMBER(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  APPLIANCE_STATUS        NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)
```

which records status changes (-1 and 0) in various industrial appliances. A record is inserted in the table each time the status is modified:

```
APPLIANCE_ID    ACTIVITY_DATE      APPLIANCE_STATUS
----------  ------------------- -----------
         1  01-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  11-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  21-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  30-jan-15 00:00:00  1
```

Now I am working on a report and I need to generate a dataset with a row for each day in the month and the corresponding appliance status:

```
APPLIANCE_ID    ACTIVITY_DATE   APPLIANCE_STATUS
----------  ------------------- -----------
         1  01-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  02-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  03-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  04-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  05-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  06-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  07-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  08-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  09-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  10-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  11-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  12-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  13-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  14-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  15-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  16-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  17-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  18-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  19-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  20-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  21-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  22-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  23-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  24-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  25-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  26-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  27-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  28-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  29-jan-15 00:00:00  0
         1  30-jan-15 00:00:00  1
         1  31-jan-15 00:00:00  1
```

Is it possible to do this via SQL or should I just use a temporary table in the software to build the dataset myself?

Thanks!

Comment: extract date part from timestamp, do group by.

Comment: See the [**Row generator method**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/).

Answer (score 4):

Oracle supports a partitioned outer join syntax that allows sparse data to be filled in where a row is not available, and in [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/outerjoin-097144.html#8) there is a methodology for filling in blanks with the most recent value as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are three techniques required in order to achieve your aim:

- Generate a list of dates
- Partitioned Outer Joins
- LAST_VALUE() analytic function to populate the "missing" values

such as:

```
with t_activity_log as (select 1 appliance_id, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 0 appliance_status from dual union all
                        select 1 appliance_id, to_date('11/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 1 appliance_status from dual union all
                        select 1 appliance_id, to_date('21/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 0 appliance_status from dual union all
                        select 1 appliance_id, to_date('30/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 1 appliance_status from dual union all
                        select 2 appliance_id, to_date('02/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 0 appliance_status from dual union all
                        select 2 appliance_id, to_date('10/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 1 appliance_status from dual union all
                        select 2 appliance_id, to_date('15/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 0 appliance_status from dual union all
                        select 2 appliance_id, to_date('26/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') activity_date, 1 appliance_status from dual),
              dates as (select to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') -1 + level dt
                        from   dual
                        connect by level <= 31) -- query to generate the list of dates; amend as appropriate to get the list of dates you're after
select tal.appliance_id,
       dts.dt,
       last_value(tal.appliance_status ignore nulls) over (partition by tal.appliance_id order by dts.dt) appliance_status
from   dates dts
       left outer join t_activity_log tal partition by (tal.appliance_id) on (dts.dt = tal.activity_date)
order by tal.appliance_id,
         dts.dt;

APPLIANCE_ID DT         APPLIANCE_STATUS
------------ ---------- ----------------
           1 01/01/2015                0
           1 02/01/2015                0
           1 03/01/2015                0
           1 04/01/2015                0
           1 05/01/2015                0
           1 06/01/2015                0
           1 07/01/2015                0
           1 08/01/2015                0
           1 09/01/2015                0
           1 10/01/2015                0
           1 11/01/2015                1
           1 12/01/2015                1
           1 13/01/2015                1
           1 14/01/2015                1
           1 15/01/2015                1
           1 16/01/2015                1
           1 17/01/2015                1
           1 18/01/2015                1
           1 19/01/2015                1
           1 20/01/2015                1
           1 21/01/2015                0
           1 22/01/2015                0
           1 23/01/2015                0
           1 24/01/2015                0
           1 25/01/2015                0
           1 26/01/2015                0
           1 27/01/2015                0
           1 28/01/2015                0
           1 29/01/2015                0
           1 30/01/2015                1
           1 31/01/2015                1
           2 01/01/2015                 
           2 02/01/2015                0
           2 03/01/2015                0
           2 04/01/2015                0
           2 05/01/2015                0
           2 06/01/2015                0
           2 07/01/2015                0
           2 08/01/2015                0
           2 09/01/2015                0
           2 10/01/2015                1
           2 11/01/2015                1
           2 12/01/2015                1
           2 13/01/2015                1
           2 14/01/2015                1
           2 15/01/2015                0
           2 16/01/2015                0
           2 17/01/2015                0
           2 18/01/2015                0
           2 19/01/2015                0
           2 20/01/2015                0
           2 21/01/2015                0
           2 22/01/2015                0
           2 23/01/2015                0
           2 24/01/2015                0
           2 25/01/2015                0
           2 26/01/2015                1
           2 27/01/2015                1
           2 28/01/2015                1
           2 29/01/2015                1
           2 30/01/2015                1
           2 31/01/2015                1
```

NB. you don't say what should happen if the first appliance_date is after the start of the date period (see appliance_id = 2 for 1st Feb), so I've left it to default to null. If you don't want those rows showing, you'll have to throw an outer query around the above SQL to filter on appliance_status is not null.

You'll also have to amend the query that generates the dates as appropriate if you want it to be different (eg. between a specified start and end date, or based on the table data, etc). There are plenty of examples around on how to generate lists of dates.